# Custom Button Arrow Carousel Antd

Tags: reactjs, icons, carousel, antd

anyone help me for customing icon antd next prev.
This my main code >>

```
<Carousel autoplay arrows={true}>
  <div>aaaaaa</div>
  <div>bbb</div>
  <div>ccc</div>
</Carousel>
```

Then my css line:

```
.slick-prev:before {
  content: "<";
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.slick-next:before {
  content: ">";
  color: red;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

So i need to change icon from content and customize from antd icon here:

```
import {LeftOutlined,RightOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons';
```

Thank you...

Comment: You need to set prevArrow and nextArrow to use the icons you imported.

Comment: then, how to insert that icon ?